# .NET: How could the Thread class be abused, were it not sealed?

Tags: .net, multithreading, security

I'm trying to understand why the `System.Threading.Thread` class is sealed .

My guess is **security** - there are several framework methods taking `Thread` parameters, that, were `Thread` not sealed, could be fed a derived, malicious type. But I can't think of actual malicious things such a type could do.

Can you think of examples?

Comment: The CLR has intimate knowledge of some BCL classes and depends on their layout.  Thread is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine if someone's derived thread class was to override things like VolatileRead and VolatileWrite that one could imagine may be used through through out the .NET runtime they could do some damage.

It may also not be for security reasons. It could be that as threads are essential to the running of many programs that implementing them functionally incorrectly would have to high a cost to the stability of the runtime.

EDIT: there is probably no performance benefit as callvirt is emitted by the compiler when calling virtual methods on sealed classes. It is possible that the JIT compiler may do this, but I have no evidence either way.

Comment: AFAIK .net doesn't turn calls to virtual methods on on sealed classes into non virtual calls.

Comment: Edited. You're right: the compile emits callvirt. Maybe I'm thinking of Java's final classes or something...

Comment: It's not about the C# compiler emitting callvirt, it's about the JITter being too dumb to optimize it out.